# Magento 2 how to read the uploaded csv from front end form

Tags: forms, csv, file-upload

Here am trying to read the csv file which is uploaded by frontend form.
but am not able to open or read the file content.
here is form file code.

```
<form class="import-shipping-form" action="http://website.co/zone_customer/Index/UploadCsv" method="POST" >
  <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <input type="file" required class="required-entry" name="my_custom_file" id="my_custom_file" />
    <button type="submit">Import</button>
</form>
```

This is the controller

```
app/code/Zone/Customer/Controller/Index/UploadCsv.php

<?php
namespace Zone\Controller\Index;

class UploadCsv extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $jsonHelper;
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
    protected $csvProcessor;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
    ) {
        $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
     public function execute()
    {
       $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
       try{
            if(isset($data['my_custom_file']['0'])) {
            $importProductRawData = $this->csvProcessor->getData($data['my_custom_file']);
             foreach ($importProductRawData as $rowIndex => $dataRow) {
                 print_r($dataRow);
             }
          } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
         }
    }
}
```

Where am doing wrong. Can I get Help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you put the acl.xml file, right away I see your controller is missing HttpPostInterface and ADMIN_RESOURCE. The more of your code we have, the better

Comment: Thannk you @Herve Tribouilloy for responding, I dont have `acl.xml` file in my module.

Comment: is your upload form a frontend or backend form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault was `submit` i was using button as submit. and for getting file values am using raw php.

```
<form class="import-shipping-form" action="<?= $url ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php// echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <input type="file" required class="required-entry" name="my_custom_file" id="my_custom_file" />
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload Products'>
</form>
```

controller file

```
try{
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
     {
         $handle = fopen($_FILES['my_custom_file']['tmp_name'], "r");
         $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
           {
             echo $data[0];
             echo $data[1];
           }
           fclose($handle);
       }
}catch (\Exception $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

now I can see the file content.

Comment: thanks for the answer mate

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $files = (array) $this->getRequest()->getFiles() I think and not $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

Comment: Thank you @Gijsve for answering, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 <?php
    namespace Zone\Controller\Index;
    
    class UploadCsv extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
        protected $resultPageFactory;
        protected $jsonHelper;
        protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
        protected $csvProcessor;
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor,
            \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
        ) {
            $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
            $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }
         public function execute()
        {
           $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
           try{
                if(isset($data['my_custom_file']['0'])) {
                $tempFile  = $data['my_custom_file']['0']['tmp_name'];
                $importProductRawData = $this->csvProcessor->getData($tempFile);
                 foreach ($importProductRawData as $rowIndex => $dataRow) {
                     print_r($dataRow);
                 }
              } catch (\Exception $e) {
                printr_r($e->getMessage());die;
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: my class  `class UploadCsv extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.

Comment: Thank you @Arunendra for answer. here am getting exception

Comment: what exception you are getting ?

Comment: actually `catch()` is added for if block, its fine. but now its blank not printing anything

Comment: See updated answer it will print the error message

Comment: thank you @Arunendra, error am getting is `File "demo.csv" does not exist`

Comment: I think file is not uploaded only name is coming, how to upload it properly